# Why Gauss divergence theorem isn't working?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, vector-fields, dirac-delta-distributions

> $\vec{E}$ is electric field
>
> $r$ is distance between source and field points
>
> $\hat{r}$ is a unit vector from source point to field point
>
> $x,y,z$ are Cartesian coordinates of field point
>
> $x',y',z'$ are Cartesian coordinates of source points
>
> $r= \left[       (x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2         \right]^{1/2} $
>
> $\rho$ is uniform charge distribution density

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \dfrac{(\hat{r})}{r^2}
&=\nabla \cdot  \left[     \dfrac{x-x'}{r^3} (\hat{i}) + \dfrac{y-y'}{r^3}(\hat{j})  + \dfrac{z-z'}{r^3}(\hat{k})    \right]\\
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(  \dfrac {x-x'}{r^3} \right) 
+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(  \dfrac {y-y'}{r^3} \right)
+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(  \dfrac {z-z'}{r^3} \right)\\
&=0 \tag1\\
\end{align}
$\text{(after some calculation, it will come out to be zero)}$

Using equation (1):

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E}
=\nabla \cdot     \left[    k\ \rho \displaystyle\int_V  \dfrac{dV}{r^2}  (\hat{r})  \right]
=k\ \rho \displaystyle\int_V  \left[  \nabla \cdot \dfrac{(\hat{r})}{r^2} \right] dV  =0$$

Now we do it in another way by applying Gauss divergence theorem and solid angle formula:

$\nabla \cdot \vec{E}
=\nabla \cdot     \left[    k\ \rho \displaystyle\int_V  \dfrac{dV}{r^2}  (\hat{r})  \right]
=k\ \rho \displaystyle\int_V \left[ \nabla.  \left( \dfrac{\hat{r}}{r^2}   \right)  \right] dV
=k\ \rho \displaystyle \iint_S \dfrac{(\hat{r})}{r^2} \cdot \vec{dS}
=4\ \pi\ k\ \rho$

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: Because your equation 1 is not valid at $r=0$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divergence of Electric Field Due to a Point Charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/378828/)

Comment: Look in the new edition Jan 09 '19 of my answer in the above given link  [Divergence of Electric Field Due to a Point Charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378828/divergence-of-electric-field-due-to-a-point-charge/378859#378859). Note that I post the first answer exactly one year ago Jan 09 ' 18.